# Using custom themes in divshot

Tags: divshot

I am just having a look into divshot and I wonder if it is possible to use custom themes?
I like the theme switcher, but I couldn't find a way to upload my themes.

Bye
 Dominik

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom theme by uploading it to any publicly readable HTTPS URL and then choosing "Custom" from the theme dropdown. From there you can paste the URL and it will replace the Bootstrap CSS for that page.